# Handle Laravel Excel::download with VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Here is what I did**

In Laravel

```
return Excel::download($report, 'coupons-report.xlsx');
```

In Vue

```
 async submitDates() {
      await this.$axios({
        url: "/exports/coupons?from=01-01-2020&to=30-03-2022", //your url
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "blob"
      }).then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "file");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      }); // Please catch me!
    },
```

**What I expect**

- An Excel file downloaded with expected data

**What actually happens**

- A file with null.

**Note**: When I use Postman and save the response as a file I get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

`Excel::download($report, 'coupons-report.xlsx')` seems not giving blob as return. You can try use this `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` as response and set `const url` to be

```
var url = new Blob([response], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
```

Comment: I tried this and I got a file with null

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to help you, but this is what I did using Laravel Excel to download the file from a VueJS component:

```
window.open("/exports/coupons?from=01-01-2020&to=30-03-2022").focus();
```

This will open a new window, download the file, and then close.

Comment: I tried this line of code already and got 404 page

Comment: Try to enter that URL in the browser, without making any requests from Vue.
It's a GET route, so it should download the file right away if everything works.

Comment: I need to pass authorization in order to hit that function